# How do i remove margin from image to a textView when having?

Tags: java, android

I got a few images and textViews in a LinearLayout. The LinearLayout is having margin top and margin bottom 8sp or so.

Problem is all my images are getting that margin aswell even if i tell them to have margin 0 the same way i told my LinearLayout to have margin 0

[image: Android image get margins when on portrait mode]
[image: Margin between image and text dissapear when on landscape]
As you see, the margin dissapear when i turn the screan to landscape mode.

What have i done wrong?

Everything is done programmatically ie no XML files is used.
Here is how i set margin on my LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout contentLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(0,8,0,8);
contentLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Solved by using
    android:adjustViewBounds
on the image

Comment: instead of margins try setting the `padding`

Comment: No result at all when setting padding.

Answer (score 0):

try to set orientation to vertical

```
contentLayout.setOrientation(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//obtain dp equivalent of pixels
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int margin = (int) (5 * scale + 0.5f);
```

Apply to your layout params.

```
//setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
params.setMargins(margin,margin,margin,margin);
```

I think you are not setting **marginLeft**

Let me know if that helps!